# OBFS4 doesnt connect in iran

Tags: censorship, pluggable-transports, obfs4

I'm using Tor Browser 6.5a1 in Iran.
Problem is obfs4 doesn't connect.
I already tried using obfs4 bridges but it wasn't helpful.

```
09/07/2016 07:29:09 ق.ظ.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/07/2016 07:29:09 ق.ظ.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/07/2016 07:29:09 ق.ظ.700 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\CPN\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
09/07/2016 07:29:16 ق.ظ.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09/07/2016 07:29:16 ق.ظ.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
09/07/2016 07:29:37 ق.ظ.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09/07/2016 07:30:06 ق.ظ.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09/07/2016 07:30:06 ق.ظ.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09/07/2016 07:30:06 ق.ظ.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a Tor Browser Bundle, and it's a common problem. the problem root is that when the browser closed - it sends `DisableNetwork 1` config to tor on-flight via control port protocol, so it stops talking to Tor network. Run your Tor **and** Browser, don't close browser and give it an hour or two - then please post FULL log if the problem will still persist